# discord.pyでID指定でユーザ情報を取得するには

Tags: python, discord

ID指定でユーザ情報を取得するにはどうすればよいでしょうか

Comment: この記事とかでは？ [IDからユーザーを取得する](https://scrapbox.io/discordjs-japan/ID%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

Answer (score 1):

```py
@commands.command(name='test')
async def test(self,ctx,member:discorrd.Member):
  await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title=f'{member}の詳細',description='説明文')
```

*注　これはコマンドフレームワークを使っている場合の書き方です。

解説:
・member:discord.Memberはmemberという引数にあらかじめdiscordMemberというメソッドを入れておいて楽にしています
以上です（）
これのほかにも`member.avatar.url`でアイコンのURLが取れたりします。
[詳細はAPIリファレンス](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/ja/stable/api.html?highlight=author#discord.abc.User)に載っています

Answer (score 1):

```py
@client.command()
async def userinfo(ctx,userid=None):
    if userid == None:
        userid = str(ctx.author.id)
    try:user = await client.fetch_user(userid)
    except:await ctx.reply("指定されたidに該当するユーザーは居ません。")
    await ctx.reply("ユーザー名: "+user.name.replace("@","＠"))
```